# One structure defined in multiple files with identical names

Tags: c, eclipse

I have a problem to determine where the structure is actually defined. In a relatively big project I have this macro in netstack.h:

```
#define NETSTACK_RDC     nullrdc_driver
```

Typing F3 button to find the definition of the nullrdc_driver four options appear on the window:
[image: Eclipse]

All the files nullrdc.c are identical but at different project tree levels.
where nullrdc_driver is:

```
const struct rdc_driver nullrdc_driver = {
  "nullrdc",
  init,
  send_packet,
  send_list,
  packet_input,
  on,
  off,
  channel_check_interval,
};
```

My question is: How could I know which definition is relevant to the function that calls nullrdc_driver?

Comment: Probably you must check includes of your projects: Preferences->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Includes. Each project need only its includes, not all dirs of all project. Then rebuild your indexer.

Comment: You can analyze makefiles to determine it. Other option is to use bisection method with on purpose errors in struct definitions.